# WebDAV LOCK implementation

Tags: c#, locking, webdav

I'm implementing a WebDAV server in C# and I want to add a lock to a file.
What is the best way to do so?

I have already tried using the FileStream class, but I'm looking for another approach.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileStream(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileStream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)